# HTML, SVG, and Javascript with XML - DOMParser not reading every other element

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I'm working on a program that saves and loads SVG data to and from an xml file and it does work, but for some reason whenever the DOMParser runs, every other element is not being read.
The XML file I am trying to read is formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<marks>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mark" d="M736 264 L736 264 L736 264 L736 265 L736 268 L736 269 L736 272 L736 277 L736 280 L736 288 L736 304 L736 312 L737 318 L740 356 L740 364 L740 376 L741 398 L742 430 L742 474 L744 488" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="A"></path>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mark" d="M1230 426 L1230 428 L1230 428 L1229 428 L1228 429 L1228 430 L1228 430 L1226 432 L1224 432 L1218 434 L1216 436 L1209 436 L1194 440 L1186 440 L1180 440 L1158 444 L1092 445 L1018 446 L928 446 L902 446" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="AA"></path>
</marks>
```

In this example, the first element is not read but the second one is. Here's the javascript code:

```js
var e = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><marks><path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mark" d="M736 264 L736 264 L736 264 L736 265 L736 268 L736 269 L736 272 L736 277 L736 280 L736 288 L736 304 L736 312 L737 318 L740 356 L740 364 L740 376 L741 398 L742 430 L742 474 L744 488" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="A"></path><path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mark" d="M1230 426 L1230 428 L1230 428 L1229 428 L1228 429 L1228 430 L1228 430 L1226 432 L1224 432 L1218 434 L1216 436 L1209 436 L1194 440 L1186 440 L1180 440 L1158 444 L1092 445 L1018 446 L928 446 L902 446" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" id="AA"></path></marks>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(e, "text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc);
```

Even at this point the XML is not being parsed correctly. Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: How are you determining that the first element is not being read?

Comment: the console.log(xmlDoc) only shows the second element. If i were to increase the number of entries, the same thing happens, the odd number elements are never shown in the log, and can not be accessed through the document's DOM methods.

Comment: Hard to say what's happening. I added the snippet so that I could run the code, and it shows the correct value in Chrome 57 on Windows 10. You could try logging `xmlDoc.children[0].children.length` and see if you get back 2 on your browser...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `"application/xml"` instead of `"text/xml"`.

Comment: Well, i just tryed it in console with hardcoded xml string, and i get correct document. Are you sure about variable "e" content?

Comment: e is the string that contains the xml. I am logging it just before passing it to the parser. Is it possible that it is an issue with the browser being used? (Overwolf), though Overwolf's browser uses chromium so I can't imagine that's the issue.